# How to update debug.keystore file after updating pc

Tags: java, android, keystore

I have a inhouse app and working fine without an issue, recently i have updated my laptop and updated android studio as well.I want to update app without user unstalling it.i have my previously generated debug.keystore file.Can somebody help...

Comment: Might be bit unclear. What do you exactly want from previously generated **debug.keystore**?

Comment: just put your previous keystore instead of new debug.keystore

Comment: @RumitPatel i have a app installed in nearly 800 users (not published in playstore) inhouse app, i changed my lap top and installed new android studio which version 3.2.1.not i cannot send updates (through web service) to users and it says cannot install APK, I have previous debug.keystore file with me, what fo i have to do now?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko is that it? you want me to restore debug.keystore which located in C/users/.android ? should i only need to replace debug.keystore file only or are there any other files?

Comment: that is the only file you need to replace. Also back it up before replacing **just in case**. But it should work after you replace it